# Can't write in a folder with permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, usergroups

I'm trying to configure my local server htdocs folder to write in it without root powers, but without the ugly way of chmod 777. I created a new group, I set it to the folder, I changed the permissions to 775 and I add my user to this new group. This is the result:

```
$ ls -ld .
drwxrwxr-x 4 nobody htdocs 4096 ago 27  2009 .
$ id asbel
uid=1000(asbel) gid=1000(asbel) grups=1000(asbel),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),1002(htdocs)
$ touch test
touch: no s’han pogut canviar les dates de «test»: S’ha denegat el permís
```

The answer of the last command says that I don't have permissions to write here.

What is wrong here? Also, I want that when I create new folders they have same group permissions since I want that other users of the group could modify them. Is it correct?

Comment: Does this also happen if you use a command other than `touch`?  The error message actually mentions setting the times on the file, which is a different operation that only works on some kinds of filesystems.

Comment: I can't make a dir with mkdir.

Comment: For the new group to take effect, you must log out and log in again (opening a new shell is not sufficient).

Comment: Haha, thank you. That was the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the new group to take effect, you must log out and log in again (opening a new shell is not sufficient)

@[n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) (originally [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557149/cant-write-in-a-folder-with-permissions#comment13665227_10557149) to this question)